# Makefile: Error1

Tags: c, makefile

I have a very simple c programme:

```
int main()
{
  return(1);
}
```

and a simple Makefile:

```
all:
    gcc -ansi -pedantic -o tmp tmp.c
    ./tmp
```

However, when I type `make` I get the following error message:

```
$ make
gcc -ansi -pedantic -o tmp tmp.c
./tmp
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

What obvious thing am I missing?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Make exits with an error if any command it executes exits with an error.

Since your program is exiting with a code of 1, make sees that as an error, and then returns the same error itself.

You can tell make to ignore errors by placing a - at the beginning of the line like this:

```
-./tmp
```

You can see more about error handling in makefiles [here](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/make-3.79/html_chapter/make_5.html#SEC48).

Comment: The link provded is not longer usable...

Comment: doesn't work when use pipeline `|`

Answer (score 9):

You're returning an error code of 1 from your application.  It's Make's job to report this as an error!

Answer (score 6):

This is because your program is returning 1.

Makes does the compilation using gcc, which goes fine (returns `0`) so it proceeds with the execution, but your program return a non-zero value, so make reports this as an error.

A program on successful completion should return `0` and return a non-zero value otherwise.