# How to fix makefile compilation terminated, error 1

Tags: c, linux, bash, gcc, makefile

I wrote a makefile for my C project, when I included all of my files in the same folder and run the following command:

```
make
```

all is fine. But when I move `map.c` & `map.h` inside mtm_map folder (which exists inside the current folder) I got an error:

```
-bash-4.2$ ls
election.c  extended_map.c  main.c  makefile  test_utilities.h  utilities.h
election.h  extended_map.h  main.o  mtm_map   utilities.c
-bash-4.2$ ls mtm_map
map.c  map.h
-bash-4.2$ make
gcc -c -DNDEBUG -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror mtm_map/map.c
mtm_map/map.c:2:23: fatal error: utilities.h: No such file or directory
 #include "utilities.h"
                       ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [mtm_map/map.o] Error 1
-bash-4.2$
```

My makefile:

```
CC = gcc
OBJS = main.o mtm_map/map.o extended_map.o election.o utilities.o
EXEC = election
DEBUG_FLAG = -DNDEBUG
COMP_FLAG = -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror

$(EXEC) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(OBJS) -o $@
main.o: main.c mtm_map/map.h election.h test_utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
mtm_map/map.o: mtm_map/map.c mtm_map/map.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
extended_map.o: extended_map.c extended_map.h mtm_map/map.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
election.o: election.c election.h mtm_map/map.h extended_map.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
utilities.o: utilities.c utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
```

Edit: The latet error I am getting:

```
gcc -c -DNDEBUG -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror main.c
gcc -c -DNDEBUG -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror mtm_map/map.c
gcc -c -DNDEBUG -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror extended_map.c
gcc -c -DNDEBUG -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror election.c
gcc -c -DNDEBUG -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror utilities.c
gcc -DNDEBUG main.o mtm_map/map.o extended_map.o election.o utilities.o -o election
gcc: error: mtm_map/map.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [election] Error 1
-bash-4.2$
```

Comment: That's a compile error. It has nothing to do with your makefile, although you could fix it by adding `-I.` to your compiler flags. Standard practice is to gather all the shared header files in the project and put them into a single folder, and then add a `-I` option pointing at that folder. Otherwise, if you move a shared header, you have to find and fix every source file which includes it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Makefile: Error1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034392/makefile-error1)

Comment: @rici Thanks a lot, I followed your advice and I did solve most of my problem "you have to find and fix every source file which includes it" Now I am getting different error, may you kindly take a look at my last edit:

Comment: @the_endian Sorry, not the same problem

Comment: You don't have `-o $@` in most of your compile recipes, and without it the default output filename is used. The default output filename is the filename (not path, just the filename) of the source file with the extension changed to `.o`

Comment: You mentioned "The default output filename is the filename (not path, just the filename) of the source file with the extension changed to .o" how is that related to my problem? (yes it fixed the issue but when I run make clean it doesn't delete map.o"

Comment: @rici another problem now I can't run "map.o" it says no rule

Comment: It doesn't delete map.o because map.o isn't in the OBJS list. map.o was created erroneously when you didn't have a `-o` option in your compile command, which resulted in creating map.o instead of mtm_map/map.o. It's going to be more complicated to write a Makefile for a project spread out over several folders, and you need to plan out which files go into which folders, and then make sure that every compile command references the right folders.

Comment: @rici Thanks, I think I can't submit my HW now after working 2 weeks on this c code, will try to talk to my professor...

Comment: Why don't you just put everything in one folder and make life easier on you?

Comment: @rici Actually there is hope: I create map.o inside mtm_map how could I move it?

Comment: @rici because that's how he want it to be

Comment: Where do you want the object files (`foo.o`) to go?

Comment: Believe me, if the source code is good, we can get all of this working within an hour.

Comment: Change the `mtm_map/map.o` recipe to `$(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) -I. $*.c -o $@` and it will cure the latest error.