# What does "make: *** [Makefile:58: install] Error 1" mean?

Tags: c, msys

Does anyone know what this error mesage means? Everything worked perfectly just an hour ago but now I keep getting these error messages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Makefile: Error1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034392/makefile-error1)

Answer (score 1):

The '1' is the exit code from some command that you ran. `make` expects commands that succeed to return 0 and a non-zero value for failure. Take a look at the rest of the output to figure out exactly what failed